# image loading loop IE7 Stack Overflow at line 0

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, stack-overflow

Im trying to load in jpeg images, frame by frame to create an sequence animation of jpeg images. I'm attempting to load them in a recursive loop using javascript. **I need to load images in linearly to achieve progressive playback of the animation. (start playback before all frames are loaded)** I get a `Stack overflow at line: 0` error from IE due to the natural recursion of the function. (My real code loads in over 60+ frames)

Here is a basic example of how I'm doing this:

```
var paths = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg']; //real code has 60+ frames
var images = [];
var load_index = 0;

var load = function(){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        if(load_index<=paths.length){
            load_index++;
            load();
        }else{
            alert('done loading');
        }
    }
    img.src = paths[load_index];
    images.push(img);
}
```

It seems I can avoid this error by using a setTimeout with an interval of 1 when calling the next step of the load. This seems to let IE "breathe" before loading the next image, but decreases the speed at which the images load dramatically.

Any one know how to avoid this stack overflow error?

http://cappuccino.org/discuss/2010/03/01/internet-explorer-global-variables-and-stack-overflows/

The above link suggests that wrapping the function to remove it from the window object will help avoid stack overflow errors. But I then see strangeness with it only getting about 15 frames through the sequence and just dies.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, don't use a recursive function for this situation, there isn't any need:

```
var paths = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'];
var images = [];
var loads = [];

/// all complete function, probably should be renamed to something with a 
/// unique namespace unless you are working within your own function scope.
var done = function(){
  alert('all loaded');
}

var loaded = function(e,t){
  /// fallbacks for old IE
  e = e||Event; t = e.target||e.srcElement;
  /// keep a list of the loaded images, you can delete this later if wanted
  loads.push( t.src );
  if ( loads.length >= paths.length ) {
    done();
  }
}

var load = function(){
  var i, l = paths.length, img;
  for( i=0; i<l; i++ ){
    images.push(img = new Image());
    img.onload = loaded;
    img.src = paths[i];
  }
}
```

In fact, as you are finding, the method you are using currently is quite intensive. Instead, the above version doesn't create a new function for each `onload` listener *(saves memory)* and will trigger off as many concurrent loads as your browser will allow *(rather than waiting for each image load)*.

*(the above has been manually typed and not tested, as of yet)*

#### update

Ah, then it makes more sense as to why you are doing things this way :) In that case then your first approach using the `setTimeout` would probably be the best solution (you should be able to use a timeout of `0`). There is still room for rearranging things to see if you can avoid that though. The following may get around the problem...

```
var paths  = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'];
var images = []; /// will contain the image objects
var loads  = []; /// will contain loaded paths
var buffer = []; /// temporary buffer
var done   = function(){ alert('all loaded'); }

var loaded = function(e,t){
  e = e||Event; t = e.target||e.srcElement; loads.push( t.src );
  /// you can do your "timing/start animation" calculation here...
  /// check to see if we are complete
  if ( loads.length >= paths.length ) { done(); }
  /// if not fire off the next image load
  else { next(); }
}

var next = function(){
  /// current will be the next image
  var current = buffer.shift();
  /// set the load going for the current image
  if ( current ) { current.img.src = current.path; }
}

var load = function(){
  var i, l = paths.length, img;
  for( i=0; i<l; i++ ){
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = loaded;
    /// build up a list of images and paths to load
    buffer.push({ img: img, path: paths[i] });
  }
  /// set everything going
  next();
}
```

If the above doesn't do it, another way of getting around the issue would be to step through your list of paths, one at a time, and append a string of image markup (that would render off-screen) to the DOM with it's own `onload="next()"` handler... `next()` would be responsible for inserting the next image. By doing this it would hand off the triggering of the load and the subsequent load event to outside of your code, and should get around stacking calls.

Comment: This looks great, however, I should have specified that I'm attempting to load the frames in linearly. So that I can calculate time to finish and start playback before all frames have been downloaded. Just at first glance, the above function will make the images load in randomly, and when they all complete, the done function is fired. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ndmweb ah ok, that makes more sense with regard to why the recursive function :) Check my answer, I've updated it with some possibilities.